# Оптимизация программы поиска количества нулей в конце факториала числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, производительность, факториал, теория-чисел

```
import math 
num = int(input())  
num = math.factorial(num) 

countZero = 0 
while (num % 10 == 0):
    num //= 10
    countZero += 1

print(countZero)
```

Comment: А выход из цикла?

Comment: Подсказка: что бы посчитать количество нулей, вовсе не нужно считать само число.

Comment: Удалил свой ответ, потому что неправильно считает начиная с 25 (нужно не кратные 5 множители считать, а еще учитывать "сколько раз" каждый множитель кратен 5).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Так годится?

```
num = int(input()) 
five = 5
zeros = 0

while five <= num:
    zeros += num // five
    five *= 5

print(zeros)
```

Comment: а что оно считает?

Comment: Количество нулей в конце Факториал числа

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну вроде как число нулей в конце факториала введенного числа... Ну или количество делителей-пятерок.

Comment: @Harry, вы кросавчег! пока я вчитывадся в вопрос - у Вас уже готово решение!

Comment: О, что-то щас нормальный результат выдаёт, а до этого какую то ерунду писало 

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм тот же что в [ответе Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266787/416121), реализация чуть проще и быстрее: вместо увеличения делителя уменьшается делимое:

```
n = int(input()) 
z = 0
while n > 0:
    n //= 5
    z += n
print(z)
```